# Javac - plugin not found

Tags: java, maven, javac

I am trying to make my own Javac plugin but things aren't going so well already :( I am following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-build-compiler-plugin and when I want to test the first basic plugin it can't find it.

When I enter the following command:

> javac -cp ./target/classes/javacplugin/ -Xplugin:Getter ./src/main/java/javacPlugin/App.java

I get this error:

> plug-in not found: Getter

How do I solve this issue?

This is my sourcetree:

[image]

This is my code for the plugin:

```
package javacplugin;

import com.sun.source.util.JavacTask;
import com.sun.source.util.Plugin;
import com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Log;

/**
 * JavacPlugin
 */
public class JavacPlugin implements Plugin {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Getter";
    }

    @Override
    public void init(JavacTask task, String... arg1) {
        Context context = ((BasicJavacTask) task).getContext();
        Log.instance(context).printRawLines(Log.WriterKind.NOTICE, "Hello from " + getName());

    }    
}
```

This is what's inside of `com.sun.source.util.Plugin`:

```
javacplugin.JavacPlugin
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>javacplugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>javacplugin</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <name>javacplugin</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
      <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
              <arg>-Xplugin:Getter</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it:

`javac -cp ./target/classes -Xplugin:Getter ./src/main/java/javacPlugin/App.java`

Is the right command, without `/javacplugin`.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need your META-INF/ in the root directory, not in resources.

"To achieve this, we need to create a file named com.sun.source.util.Plugin with content which is our plugin’s fully qualified class name (com.baeldung.javac.SampleJavacPlugin) and place it in the META-INF/services directory."
From the referenced baeldung article

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work, but it works now. See my answer.